# ¿Uso correcto de las reglas css y evitar que regla css aplique cambios a otras etiquetas?

Tags: css, css3

> Optimizando las reglas de los estilos `css`

En este estilo `css` puedo sustituir 7 líneas y menorar una regla.

```
.showing h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "raleway";
  font-weight: 300;
}

.showing h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "raleway";
  font-weight: 300;
}

.showing h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "raleway";
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Optimizada la regla de esta manera:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'OpenSans', Roboto, Lato;
  background-color: #fff;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

#showing {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/*Regla optimizada*/

.showing h1, h2, h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "raleway";
  font-weight: 300;
}
.showing h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

/*Esta es una regla de prueba*/
#prueba {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="showing">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="showing">
      <h1>Contenido de prueba</h1>
      <h2>Segundo contenido de prueba</h2>
      <h3>Último contenido de prueba</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Aquí surge el problema -->
<div id="prueba">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sinestilo">
      <h1>Contenido de prueba</h1>
      <h2>Segundo contenido de prueba</h2>
      <h3>Último contenido de prueba</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El problema es, que al optimizar esta regla `.showing h1, h2, h3 {}` se aplican cambios a las otras etiquetas `h1, h2, h3` con la mismas reglas.

Me suponía que solo debería aplicarse a la dependencia de la clase `.showing h1, h2, h3 {}` y no aplicar cambios a las otras etiquetas `h1, h2, h3` no enlazadas a la regla `.showing`

Debido al error, se me presentó la duda del uso correcto de las reglas `css`

```
.estilo.otroestilo{} <- o -> .estilo, .otroestilo{}
.estilo>h1>h2 <- o -> .estilo h1>h2
.estilo, h1, h2, h3 <- o -> .estilo h1, h2, h3
#estilo#otroestilo{} <- o -> #estilo, #otroestilo{}
```

Comment: `.showing h1, h2, h3 { ... }` solo está haciendo referencia al `h1` dentro de `.showing`, los otros encabezados son generales, por lo cual también obtendrán ese mismo estilo que estás definiendo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenar reglas con comas, es equivalente a tener reglas completamente nuevas para cada condición de las separadas por comas.

Entonces, la regla: `.showing h1, h2, h3 {}` es equivalente a:

```
.showing h1 {}
h2 {}
h3 {}
```

Como tú lo que quieres es aplicar la regla cuando la clase `showing` sea padre de etiquetas `h1`, `h2` o `h3`, necesitas repetir la condición:

```
`.showing h1, .showing h2, .showing h3 {}
```

Y no hay manera de agrupar esa disyunción para ahorrarte escribir `.showing` tantas veces.

En el caso de:

```
.estilo > h1 > h2
```

Aquí no agrupas reglas. Aquí tienes una sola condición, (un `h2`, hijo de un `h1`, hijo de una etiqueta de clase `.estilo`), mientras que la "coma" no es un operador para definir condiciones (como `>p`), sino que más bien, agrupa condiciones completamente independientes entre sí.

**Off-topic (petición en comentario):** Otros "operadores" para definir condiciones, los más comunes, son `#` y `.`, que sirven para filtrar por el atributo `id` y `class`:

```
<div id="pepe"> <!-- div 1 -->
  <div class="inner"> <!-- div 2 -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="jose"> <!-- div 3 -->
   <div class="inner"> <!-- div 4 -->
   </div>
   <div> <!-- div 5 -->
   </div> 
   <table class="inner"> <!-- div 6 -->
   </table>
</div>
```

Para este *snippet* HTML, las siguientes reglas seleccionan los siguientes `div`s:

```
#pepe {} /* div 1 */
.inner {} /* divs 2, 4 y 6 */
#jose > .inner {} /* divs 4 y 6 */
#jose > div /* divs 4 y 5 */
#jose > div.inner /* div 6 */
```

Como restricción adicional, NO PUEDE HABER dos elementos HTML con igual atributo ID (en realidad, puedes, pero no debes), pero tantos elementos con igual clase como desees.

Comment: Gracias @Peregring-lk ahora lo entiendo, puedes reforzar tu respuesta  detallando un poco más estos parámetros (`. # >`) con algunos ejemplos de su uso ¿Donde? ¿Cuando? ¿O para que? para finalizar con mi pregunta +1 Saludos.

Comment: @J.Doe Done (aunque no debería, dado que la pregunta original ya estaba contestada).

Answer (score 1):

Trabajar con CSS tiene que ser una tarea sencilla y bien definida. Existen muchas buenas prácticas, pero existe una que es casi primordial en largos estilos: OOCSS (object oriented css).

Tu problema puede solucionarse tan solo haciendo lo siguiente:

```
.showing h1,
.showing h2,
.showing h3 {
  ...
}
```

Sin embargo, creo que teniendo ciertas buenas prácticas puedes tener una hoja de estilos más eficiente.

**OOCSS**

Object oriented CSS es una técnica popularizada hace algunos años, la cual consta básicamente del principio [separación de intereses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separaci%C3%B3n_de_intereses), el cual nos dice que cada módulo en una aplicación debe tener un interés/preocupación bien definido y limitarse a éste.

Éste paradigma nos permite escribir código CSS modular y poder integrar los módulos de manera sencilla sin crear redundancia. Veamos un ejemplo:

```css
.box {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.gold {
  background-color: gold;
}
.small {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
.large {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
.rounded {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box green small"></div>
<div class="box gold"></div>
<div class="box red large"></div>
<div class="box blue rounded"></div>
```

Como se puede observar podemos componer una caja como si fuese lego: podemos darle un tamaño, un color, redondeado, sin crear ningún tipo de dependencias y redundancia.

---

Aplicando OOCSS a tu código, quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'OpenSans', Roboto, Lato;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#showing {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/*Regla optimizada*/

.header {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "raleway";
  font-weight: 300;
}
.header.xl {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.header.medium {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.medium-bold {
  font-weight: 500;
}

/*Esta es una regla de prueba*/
#prueba {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="showing">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="showing">
      <h1 class="header xl medium-bold">Contenido de prueba</h1>
      <h2 class="header xl medium-bold">Segundo contenido de prueba</h2>
      <h3 class="header medium medium-bold">Último contenido de prueba</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Aquí surge el problema -->
<div id="prueba">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sinestilo">
      <h1 class="medium-bold">Contenido de prueba</h1>
      <h2 class="medium-bold">Segundo contenido de prueba</h2>
      <h3 class="medium-bold">Último contenido de prueba</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El documento HTML debe especificar qué reglas usar y no al revés. Haciendo tus estilos modulares te permite reutilizar código y eliminar redundancia.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo quieres cambiar el estilo de los encabezados dentro de .showing no? Bueno si es así, puedes acceder a esos elementos así:

```
.showing h1, .showing h2, .showing h3 {
      ...;
}
```